# How to mock HTTP authentication in Flask for testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm just put HTTP authentication for my Flask application and my test is broken. How do I mock `request.authentication` to make the test pass again?

Here's my code.

server_tests.py

```
def test_index(self):
    res = self.app.get('/')

    self.assertTrue('<form' in res.data)
    self.assertTrue('action="/upload"' in res.data)
    self.assertEquals(200, res.status_code)
```

server.py

```
def check_auth(username, password):
    """This function is called to check if a username /
    password combination is valid.
    """
    return username == 'fusiontv' and password == 'fusiontv'

def authenticate():
    """Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth"""
    return Response(
    'Could not verify your access level for that URL.\n'
    'You have to login with proper credentials', 401,
    {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return authenticate()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

@app.route("/")
@requires_auth
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [How do I mock dependencies of the views module of my Flask application in flask-testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046124/how-do-i-mock-dependencies-of-the-views-module-of-my-flask-application-in-flask/33046125#33046125), you can mock it via the import chain.

Assuming `server_tests` imports `application` imports `server`, you probably want something like:

server_tests.py

```
def setUp(self):
    application.server.request.authorization = MagicMock(return_value=True)
```