# How do I mock dependencies of the views module of my Flask application in flask-testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-testing

As a minimal example, my Flask application has a `views` module like

```
from flask import render_template
from something import some_service

def home():
    foo = some_service.do_thing('bar')
    return render_template('index.html', foo=foo)
```

I've got a test setup like

```
from application import app
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        return app

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()

    def test_home(self):
        rv = self.app.get('/home')
        ???
```

How do I write `test_home` so that it asserts that `some_service.do_thing('bar')` was called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python `mock` on elements of the `views` module by accessing it through the `application` module imported in your test module. Your test module should read something like:

```
import application
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        application.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        application.app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        return application.app

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = application.app.test_client()

    def test_home(self):
        mock_service = mock.MagicMock()
        application.views.some_service = mock_service
        self.app.get('/home')
        mock_service.do_thing.assert_called_with('bar')
```